# Changing the parameters/settings of my subscription

Tags: support

Honestly I don't know where else to put this question, so here goes.

I would like to subscribe to certain tags, but I do not want to receive daily mails, each of a different tag. How do I change this? Thanks. ;)

Comment: Seems to be answered on [meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78107/email-subscription-to-a-combination-of-tags-using-and-operator)